# Found a bug looks like a true bug but it has a mowhak

Tags: species-identification, entomology

It looks strange found it today what is it? [image]

Comment: Looks like some kind of treehopper.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a look around the [help] and take a [tour] to see what is considered a good question.  For species identification, we at least need a location (not just country - more specific) and at least one high resolution photo,  preferably several as ID is tricky without being able to see all the parts of the insect. Leafhopper of some sort, which one, I don't know - there are ~20,000 species worldwide.

Comment: Please [edit] to include your location, or this is just not detailed enough to narrow efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

This inscent is a [treehoppper or thorn bug (Membracidae)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treehopper). They belong to the Auchenorrhyncha.

Membracidae have a distinct transformed and enlarged (sometimes larger than the body itself) pronotum that often forms unusual structures - such as the "mowhak" on the photo or horns as the [buffalo treehopper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_treehopper). These unusual shapes are thought to be camouflage or mimicry.
Besides, their body shape is typical for planthoppers: an inclined head, their "rooftop" wings, a proboscis to suck plant sap, short antenna and relatively short, but powerful jumping legs.